# Java EE 6 Maven Project Setup in Netbeans - some configuration issues?

Tags: java, maven-2, netbeans, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

I've been trying to set up a Java EE 6 Maven project via New Project -> Maven -> Maven Enterprise Application.

However, when I try to run the application I've been running into a couple problems:

1. I had to change the the http port that Glassfish listens on because the port it chose (8080) was already used. I went into the domain.xml file and changed the port to 8081. But when I try and run the application, netbeans is opening the browser with port 8080 still. Is there a way to change this, so netbeans opens the browser with port 8081?
2. Why when I run the web application why is https being used instead of http? When https is being used its not finding the index.jsp page...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the "Services" tab, under "Servers" find the item that represents your Glassfish instance. Right-click on it, select "Properties". Change the location field to "localhost:8081".

Comment: The Location field is grayed out, so it won't let me change its value. I'm using NetBeans 6.9, if that helps at all...

Comment: OK, I just tried it here, and I can't edit the field either. My mistake - it looked like it would be editable. Try creating a new server profile, name it something like "Glassfish-8081" for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, once I re-registered the server using netbeans, it stopped trying to use https as well.